# Find lost Android tablet without SIM card

Tags: tablet

I lost my **Nexus 7 Android tablet** in **February 2015**. I noticed on Play Store settings that **it was online on March 18, 2016**. The device had my google account configured. So I guess Google logged an event when the device came online.

However I am unable to view the tablet anywhere else i.e., Android Device 
Manager or Google's Timeline (which shows placed visited by me on the given days).

In fact my device still gets listed under the "Choose a Device" option on Play Store!

I want to check

1) Is there any Google tool which can help me find the device's location picked up on March 18, 2016

2) Could the device's settings have been erased by whoever found the tablet (I think you can erase all device data without logging in - is that correct?)

3) Is the device lost forever - any way I can find some details of the device?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.google.ca/android/devicemanager considering you account info is still on the device. and yes if you don't have a password set they can delete your data from the recovery.

Comment: As i had mentioned, device manager doesn't show the device. The only trace noticed is in Google Play Store Settings where the last accessed time is shown.